# kendoUI angularJS , required validation no fired when using k-cascade-from

Tags: angularjs

so , i have two drop downs (kendo-drop-downs) and the second one is cascading from the first ,,, and both have ng-required ,,, why the second one's required validation is not fired when it is dimmed ??????
http://dojo.telerik.com/iwuFA/90
to see what i mean ,, the initial status is that the first one's required is fired and the second is not :/ 
and further , try selecting "bassan" from first , then "hassan" from second , then go back to the first and select the default "select first" option ,,, u will see that also this doesn't fire the required validation of the second drop down

plz help